# C# Console - Console.ReadLine returns wrong output

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have here a C# Console application, in which when I allow the user to input a certain number of records, the program will generate a quote number. This is for me to test the algorithm I formulated before I implement this in my program.

Example, when I input 23 (assuming this is the current record count in the database), the program will output "CQ-13-04-0023". But I got an output of "CQ-13-04-0051". My objective is when the series number in the given quote number reaches 9999, it will reset to 0001 when the number of records in the database reaches 10000 and above.

Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string QuoteRefNum = "";
        string seriesCount = "";
        DateTime year = DateTime.Now;
        string strYear = year.ToString("yy");
        string strMonth = year.ToString("MM");

        Console.Write("Input the number of records: ");
        int numberOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

        numberOfRecords++;

        if (numberOfRecords == 0)
        {
            seriesCount = "000" + numberOfRecords++;
        }
        else if (numberOfRecords >= 1 && numberOfRecords <= 9)
        {
            seriesCount = "000" + numberOfRecords;
        }
        else if (numberOfRecords >= 10 && numberOfRecords <= 99)
        {
            seriesCount = "00" + numberOfRecords;
        }
        else if (numberOfRecords >= 100 && numberOfRecords <= 999)
        {
            seriesCount = "0" + numberOfRecords;
        }
        else if (numberOfRecords >= 1000 && numberOfRecords <= 9999)
        {
            seriesCount = numberOfRecords.ToString();
        }
        else if (numberOfRecords >= 10000 && numberOfRecords <= 99999)
        {
            string newSetOfRecords = numberOfRecords.ToString();
            int tempNumber = 0;

            newSetOfRecords.Remove(0, 1);
            tempNumber = Convert.ToInt32(newSetOfRecords);

            if (tempNumber == 0)
            {
                seriesCount = "000" + tempNumber++;
            }
            else if (tempNumber >= 1 && tempNumber <= 9)
            {
                seriesCount = "000" + tempNumber;
            }
            else if (tempNumber >= 10 && tempNumber <= 99)
            {
                seriesCount = "00" + tempNumber;
            }
            else if (tempNumber >= 100 && tempNumber <= 999)
            {
                seriesCount = "0" + tempNumber;
            }
            else if (tempNumber >= 1000 && tempNumber <= 9999)
            {
                seriesCount = tempNumber.ToString();
            }

        }

        QuoteRefNum = "CQ" + strYear + "-" + strMonth + "-" + seriesCount;

        Console.WriteLine("The quote reference number is: " + QuoteRefNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Your code totally wrong, with 23 you input you execute numberOfRecords++ and then print out QuoteRefNum = "CQ" + strYear + "-" + strMonth + "-" + seriesCount; so result : CQ13-04-0024. You should debug and verify your code post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
        int numberOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
```

It is returning the `ASCII` value.

Change it to:

```
        int numberOfRecords;
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfRecords);
```

And remove `numberOfRecords++`

**Explanation of what's going on:**

The reason why you are getting `51` is because when you enter `23` number of records is set to `50` and then you increment the variable to `51` via `numberOfRecords++`

Comment: Hmmm is that not just a valid input check? If '23' is entered on the command line as op says; then Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()) should return 23

Comment: @daveL - Console.Read() is returning the ASCII value not the integer inputted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Darren for the explanation. I was not familiar with console application, so I haven't checked out Console.Read().

Answer (score 1):

Problem is  `Console.Read();` when you type 23 end enter key `Read()` will return key value of first input character that is `2`. ASCII Character value of `2` is 50

So you will get 51 after `numberOfRecords++` as result

change  `Console.Read();` to  `Console.ReadLine();` and remove `numberOfRecords++`